# Carousel Not Working using BootStrap4 version 4.5

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, slider, carousel

I am making a carousel and it is sliding but the arrows or the "underscores" at the bottom are not working. I used a carousel without them it worked fine and I copied this directly from Bootstrap's site.

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

The arrows are listed at the bottom under anchor tags Previous and Next.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <style>
  .con {
  /*  background-color: #a1a1a1;*/
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }



  </style>
</head>
<body>



  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  </nav>

  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="pic/HuskySnow1Cropped.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Frist Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="pic/PuppyTank2Cropped.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Second Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="pic/SmileyDog3Cropped.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Third Slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="pic/YawnDog4Cropped.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="Fourth Slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>



</body>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>


</html>
```

Please let me know what you are thinking.

Comment: Your slider is not working because you are missing jquery script. Add this   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> before popper.min.js script.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. This is much simpler.

**Note** You won't see images as I haven't included in it. However, you could see the images changing after 2 secs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Make the image fully responsive */
    
    .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ul class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- The slideshow -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1100" height="500">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem bro.

But it's not your fault, there is some problem with the bootstrap.min.css file in v4.5

Solution: Replace

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

**No need to change any other CDN link in your code.**

Hope this helps!    It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but hope this help. I think the problem is the version of boostrap. I have the same problem but after update the newest, everything is fine. You can take a look of Starter template at here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/       ---- good luck